# Remove query params from url react-router-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-dom, react-router-redux

I am trying to remove query params from url on a user action, using react-router-redux. On user action I am dispatching the following action:

```
dispatch(push({
  pathname: url,
  search: ''
});
```

But this is not removing the query param from url. What are the other ways to achieve this?

Comment: you can redirect to same url without query params

Comment: @NaveenHeroorkar Yes, tried that using dispatch(push(url)), but it's not removing the query params

Comment: Try `this.props.history.replace(url)`

Comment: This can help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952473/how-do-you-remove-query-params-from-the-current-route/50956125#50956125